# QT: Remove space between QLabel in QGridLayout

Tags: qt, label, spacing, qgridlayout

I Added some QLabels with different colors to A QGridLayout as Layout of a QWidget,
now I have a spacing between each Qlabel to the next and I want to remove it. I tried to set the margin of the Labels to "0" and the Alignment of the GridLayout to "0" but it didnt worked very good. i thought the space is maybe the border of the Labels but i checked.
do you have any idea?

Comment: Look at the docs for the layout itself. There's things with "spacing" in their name at the very top.

Answer (score 3):

Didnt belive i missed this :O thank yout Mat
the solutions was:

```
layout->setHorizontalSpacing(0);
layout->setVerticalSpacing(0);
```

thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can try setting the spacing:

> layout->setSpacing(0);

If that doesn't do it, you can also try setting the contents margins to zero:

> layout->setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0);