# Set grid spacing using Qt

Tags: qt, grid

I have created a Gird with `QPushButton`. I would like to set each button spacing to 0. As you can see I set it, but there is still little padding around the button, and I would like to eliminate it.

```
QVector<QVector<QPushButton*>> buttons(10);

void MainWindow::createGrid() {
    QFrame *frame = new QFrame(this);
    QGridLayout *layout = new QGridLayout(frame);

    layout->setMargin(0);
    layout->setSpacing(0);

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i){
        buttons[i].resize(10);

        for(int j = 0; j < 10; ++j){
            QPushButton *button = new QPushButton("0");
            button->setMinimumSize(50,50);
            button->setMaximumSize(50,50);

            layout->addWidget(button,i,j);

            buttons[i][j] = button;
        }
    }

    setCentralWidget(frame);  

}
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [QT: Remove space between QLabel in QGridLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388092/qt-remove-space-between-qlabel-in-qgridlayout)

Comment: layout->setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0); still not solve my problem

Comment: Are you sure the apparent space isn't actually part of the buttons themselves?  What happens if you do `button->setFlat(true)` -- do you still see the space?

Comment: The border disappear, but nothing else changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you already have proper settings, spacing is correct parameter for you task.

The issue here is that you `QStyle` (looks like you are using Windows and your default style is `QWindowsVistaStyle`). That style just draws `QPushButton` in this way, without Bevels (more info about button structure: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/style-reference.html#push-buttons).

To ensure that it is your issue - you can setup custom style in QtDesigner and check application preview with another style:

Settings->Preferences->Forms->Print/Preview Configuration->Style
[image]

With Fusion style it will looks like this:
[image]

To set custom style from code you need to add something like this:

```
QApplication app(argc, argv);
app.setStyle(QStyleFactory::create("Fusion"));
```